# How to run a debugger in an RSpec request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

**Update: This actually works fine. Please ignore this question**

I'm used to being able to call `byebug` in an RSpec controller test, but this does nothing in an RSpec [request spec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails#request-specs).... it doesn't produce an error, but it also doesn't have any effect. Is there some other way to drop into a debugger in request specs?

E.g.:

```
# spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
describe UsersController do
  describe "GET #index logged out" do
    it "returns 401 when not logged in" do
      get :index, format: :json_api
      expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
      byebug
    end
  end
end
```

Above drops into the debugger, below does not:

```
# specs/requests/users_request_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
describe "users", type: :request do
  describe 'GET /users logged out' do
    it 'returns 401 when not logged in' do
      get '/users'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
      byebug
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your file in my environment

```
# specs/requests/users_request_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
describe "companies", type: :request do
  describe 'GET /companies logged out' do
    it 'returns 401 when not logged in' do
      binding.pry # => this stops execution
      get '/companies.json_api'
      expect(response).to have_http_status(401)
      binding.pry # => this does not
    end
  end
end
```

Reason for me:

```
Failure/Error: get '/companies.json_api'

     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches [GET] "/companies.json_api"
     # ./spec/requests/users_request_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

For it to reach the debugger, there should not be exception. Are you sure that is the same case with you?

Comment: @simon can you let me know if this works?

Comment: Thanks for testing. Sorry, I should have had `/users` instead of `/companies.json_api`. I've edited the question.

Comment: Thanks for testing this! I was wrong, so I'm going to update it to say that. I'll accept your answer.